# Method of Undetermined Coefficients example question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

I'm trying to solve the following question:

$$y'^{(4)}+y''=3x^2+4\sin x-2\cos x$$

My attempt at solution:

First I have tried to find complementary function of homogenous form by plugging in e^tx and I get the following
$$t^4+t^2=0$$
and I seem to miss a root as I found the complementary function as the following:

$$y=c_1+c_2\sin x+c_3\cos x$$ missing the $$c_4x$$

and I know how to find particular integral. Why and how did I miss a root?

Comment: This question is taken from Differential equations book by Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t = 0 is a repeated root so you should try adding $c_2x$.

Comment: Oh god thank you. It was so simple but yet I fail to see it